# use pattern with @JsonFormat for java.time.Instant. Do not want to manually write code for it and use annotations

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, java.time.instant

unsupportedtemporaltypeexception with @JsonFormat on POJO with the property of type `java.time.Instant`

> **Error** *java.time.temporal.unsupportedtemporaltypeexception unsupported field yearofera*

I do not want to write a manual code for conversion. Please suggest some other way

```java
class MyClass{
    @JsonFormat(shape= Shape.String, pattern="yyyy-dd-mm HH:mm:ss")
    private Instant createTime;
}
```

Comment: Use LocalDateTime in place of Instant

Comment: @dai i do not want to do it manually, that is the last option. Instead in that case i'll write my own custom annotation to do so

Comment: @kumesana As a standard in our entities we are using Instant and would not like to change it

Comment: Please, I'm begging you, stick to the standard ISO-8601 format. It's unambiguous, and usable by any client. The standard exists for a reason. Don't use your own, proprietary, ambiguous format (which BTW doesn't even contain the month).